# Jquery validation error messages are not hiding, why

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am using jquery validation and jquery unobtrusive validation plugins. I am trying to hide error message, but error message are not hiding. I have created a js fiddle:

[Fiddle Link](http://jsbin.com/leyacefi/16/edit)

Following is the code which i used in the fiddle:

**Html**

```
<form id="form">
    Name:
    <input data-val="true" data-val-length="The field First Name must be a string with a minimum length of 3 and a maximum length of 15." data-val-length-max="15" data-val-length-min="3" name="FirstName" type="text" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid help-block" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</form>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
```

Hide

**JS**

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
   $("#form").data("validator").hideErrors();
});
```

What i am missing here and why hideErrors() function are not working ??

**Edit**

I don't know why you guys are not keeping jquery unobtrusive validation in mind while giving answers. Almost all answer are just focusing on how to hide error messages without worrying about the existing functionality which could be break if we just hide the message. I already mention that i want the answer of

**Why hideErrors() function of jquery validator object is not working ?**

I have also created a simplest possible fiddle which demonstrate my problem, [check this](http://jsbin.com/leyacefi/16/edit).

Comment: We all understand what your problem is, but the jQuery validator isn't developed to hide messages on a click. This is very user-unfriendly because you can't see what you are doing wrong and many users will think that the site is not working. That's why. So, I think, there is no real method to hide the messages(see documentation, the `hideErrors()` is called in the `resetForm`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to hide validation error messages, than you should use *resetForm* function instead of *hideErrors* function. As other mentioned in their answers, *resetForm* internally call *hideErrors* function.

But here's the twist comes, when you will try to use *resetForm* function it will not work because of the way *jquery.validate.unobtrusive* plugin works.

*jquery.validate.unobtrusive* plugin override the *errorClass* and *errorElement* property of *jquery.validate* plugin.

*From jquery.validate.unobtrusive plugin code Line-109*

```
    .... 
    if (!result) {
        result = {
            options: {  
                errorClass: "input-validation-error",
                errorElement: "span",
                errorPlacement: $.proxy(onError, form),
    ...
```

So when you will call *resetForm* function on validator's object, *jquery.validate* plugin can't find error labels to remove so validation error message will not remove.

Now you have two options to remove error messages:

**Option - 1**

You can edit *jquery.validate.unobtrusive* plugin code and replace *errorClass* and *errorElement* values with the following values:

```
    errorClass: "error",
    errorElement: "label",
```

These are the default values which *jquery.validate* plugin use.

**Option - 2**

You can write your own code which will do the trick and by this way you do not have to modify the plugin code. [Here is the code which you can use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360925/how-to-clear-jquery-validate-errors#14831537) with little modifications mentioned below:

```
        // get the form 
        var form = $("#formId");

        // get validator object
        var validator = form.validate();

        // get errors that were created using jQuery.validate.unobtrusive
        var errors = form.find(".field-validation-error span");

        // trick unobtrusive to think the elements were succesfully validated
        // this removes the validation messages
        errors.each(function () { validator.settings.success($(this)); })

        //this is optional, only needed if you defined 
        //custom unhighlight function  
        if (validator.settings.unhighlight) {
            for (i = 0, elements = validator.invalidElements() ; elements[i]; i++) {
                validator.settings.unhighlight.call(validator, elements[i], validator.settings.errorClass, validator.settings.validClass);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Trying to understand better how it's working. Why must you "trick unobtrusive to think the elements were successfully validated" as opposed to just removing the error elements from the DOM? I tried $(myform).remove(".field-validation-error") and somehow the error messages remain.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `$(".help-block").toggle();` or `$(".help-block").hide();` to fix this.

http://jsbin.com/leyacefi/10/edit?html,js,output

I've made a workaround. Check if it fit to your needs:

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
    $(".help-block").hide();
});

$('#form').keyup(function(){
  $(".help-block").show();
});
```

http://jsbin.com/leyacefi/11/

**To answer your question:**

The function `hideErrors` is calling `this.addWrapper( this.toHide ).hide();` so it first runs the function `addWrapper` that returns the context and after that it is calling the `hide` function. The function `hide` calls the `showHide` function and one of the paramets is `elements`.  `elements.length` will be 0 and therefore it will never reach till the `elem.style.display = show ? values[ index ] || "" : "none";` where the CSS will be set. So, the property will never change.

Comment: After clicking on hide button messages hide, but it is not showing again on wrong input and i am expecting the answers of the question WHY hideErrors() FUNCTION ARE NOT WORKING ?

Comment: You have to be clear and put that in your question. At the moment you are asking how to hide them and that's what I showed you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#hide").click(function(){ 
            $("span.help-block").hide();
        }); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to read the documentation before using any plugin. 
If you see the validator plugin documentation, it is clearly mentioned that

```
    Validator

The validate method returns a Validator object that has a few public methods that you can  use to trigger validation programmatically or change the contents of the form. The validator object has more methods, but only those documented here are intended for usage
```

The method .hideErrors() is not listed in the documentation. So as per documentation, you shouldn't use it.

But in javascript(you can say jquery) many are possible. So even if they dont allow you to call it on the jquery object, you can call it on DOM .

Simply use like this.

```
   $("#hide").click(function(){
   $("#form").data("validator")[0].hideErrors();
});
```

Comment: I already read the documentation, and BTW your given solution is not working, you can test it in my fiddle which i have Linked with the question

Comment: I dont know what do you means by local, but check this fiddle http://jsbin.com/leyacefi/12/edit , your solution is not working

Comment: Local means: copy and paste the code in a notepad file and save it as .html and running it from browser. And your requirement is, you dont want the error messages to show on entering less than 3 chars or more than 15 chars, am I correct? If that is your requirement, can you try it in your local with and without [0]